# paytm - payment gateway integration using python as backend language

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, backend, paytm

I have to put the python code on server  as mentioned "Copy the pythonKit folder(according to your python version) into the root folder of your server (like /var/www/html)".

can you please guide how to execute it in aws. i am new with python and aws.

i had tried running it on local server but got response as 501.

This is the code to be executed.

https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Web_Sample_Kit_Python

This is the link for steps.
https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/payment-gateway/

i am not able to execute step 2.

I have to know the steps to execute it on aws. shall i use a lambda function or put this code onto ec2 root directory.